# Matlab - Error bars added to column plot instead of regular line plot, and stacked 2x2

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to create a 2x2 plot with error bars, where each mean is represented by a column rather than by a marker (data point), something like this:

[image]

The errorbar function in Matlab seems to not have the option to make columns instead of simple markers, and also no option to stack the four entities as 2x2, instead giving me something that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a bar plot with the function bar(Y), which will draw one bar for each element in Y. So if your data has 2 columns, the plot will be 2x2. You can then add errorbars with the errorbar function, and specify the linespec 'x' per example, to avoid the lines between the markers.

figure

hold on

bar(data)

errorbar(data,'x')

hold off

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work to add error bars to the columns created by bar (I also need to type a "hold on" in between ;) ). But the stacking (i.e. separation) of the four bars does not occur, how would that be achieved?  I am happy to do some post-processing of the graph in some image editing software (e.g. to insert asterisks), but the two sets of 2 columns would need to be separated in the original plot...

Comment: You're right about the hold on, I'll edit that!
For the stacking, it depends on the way your data is formatted. From http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html , the default Bar Group Style is "grouped", which is defined by :

"Display one group for each row in y.
If y is an m-by-n matrix, then bar displays m groups of n vertical bars, where m is the number of rows and n is the number of columns in y.
If y is a vector of length n, then bar displays one group of n bars. The bar function treats all vectors as column vectors."

Comment: btw I was confused as I remembered a different name and picture for the person who had helped initially! I guess picture was a bit too pretty for StackOverflow though :-p THanks again for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Hahaha yeah well I created my account a few days ago and didn't change the default settings. Most of the accounts here seems pretty anonymous :P
Anyway, glad I could help!